# slick slider выводить последние слайды

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Добрый день, есть ли в слике возможность выводить не первые скажем 5 слайдов, а последние 5 ?

Comment: Поисковик для чего?

Comment: дадите ссылочку ?

Comment: и кстати то что мы тут пишем и есть поисковик

Comment: Поищите в интернете, говорю. Если есть, то будет написано. А если вам нужно, что бы кто-то помог сделать это, то задавайте конкретный вопрос с кодом

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kepamuk/keb63jf1/ вот пример, как отображать последние 7 слайдов вместо первых 7

Comment: Ну, хорошо. Я рад, что вы нашли пример :)

Comment: только это мой пример, но проблема так и не решена

Comment: А нельзя поставить эти последние 5 слайдов в начало?

Comment: нет к сожалению нельзя

Comment: нужен эффект что мы листаем назад, и достаем слайды сзади а не спереди

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.slideshow').slick({
    initialSlide: n
});`

Comment: ошибку выдает...

Comment: Вы же поставили там не n, а конкретное число?

Comment: да теперь разобрался )))) спасибо вам !